# How Do I Change the Label of a Cpanel Icon?

Tags: cpanel

The [Cpanel](http://www.cpanel.net/) product for Linux has a way with its SDK to create a new icon for your own custom form and PHP scripts to do various tasks. I joined a project where the original developer is no longer there, and left no documentation. We can change the PHP scripts and the form, but we have not been able to figure out how to change the label for the Cpanel icon that is shown to customers on this hosting plan.

How do we change the label on our custom cpanel icon? What file do we edit? Where do we make the change? Do we have to do anything after this editing in order for the change to be seen by all the customers?

Answer (score 1):

On shared hosting you need at least WHM access.
If you have WHM access, you will see in cPanel a new functionality called Branding cPanel, in there you can play with css files and html files used to change the look and feel of you cPanel.

Anyway it's not an easy task. To change a label you would probably have to find the id of such label and using the branding editor upload a javascript file in the cPanel header that gets the id of the DOM object of the icon you want to chnage the label.

I mean in the branding editor I don't rememebr you can change a label of an icon, but just the icon image.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the cPanel documentation for branding/customization

http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/WHMDocs/AdvancedBrandingGuide